# How i can add my content in body of request? Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a json request (generated with Postman app). I'm pretty sure my API is working correctly. How can I send a POST request with my content in the body using Groovy?

I run this code, but I get a 500 error. This is due to incorrect parameters in my request.
Sorry, my code look bad, because I don’t know what other methods to use and I decided to slip the line on my forehead.

The code:

```
def rest = new RESTClient('http://logicased-mog.service.btlab.ru/')
def response = rest.post(
path: 'alfresco/s/mog/outgoing/createOutgoing',
headers: [Authorization:"user1 user1"],
body: [fromSoo: 'true',
      attachments: [],
      signer: 'jfjf',
      executor: 'kjdf',
      isElectronicSign: 'true',
      shortDescription : 'dskjh',
      sheetsNumber : 3,
      note: 'dshsd',
      reviewList : [],
      NodeRef: '',
      apps : 5],
requestContentType: 'application/json' )
response.responseData
```

return response.contentType

JSON request (will be validated with Postman app):

```
{
"fromSoo": true,
"attachments": [
    {
        "attachmentNodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/2c300b5a-8646-45ea-afc4-c8a4a6a2db55",
        "attachmentCategory": "1"
    },
    {
        "attachmentNodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/d71d31f7-c1fe-434a-8774-6dbb77bd135b",
        "attachmentCategory": "2"
    },
    {
        "attachmentNodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/faf06ad7-6707-4926-8c45-0e4d1d9b482e",
        "attachmentCategory": "3"
    }
],
"signer": "qqqe",
"executor": "qqqw",
"isElectronicSign": true,
"shortDescription": "short",
"sheetsNumber": 3,
"copies": "4",
"responseTo": "workspace://SpacesStore/0fc89bec-7b62-4862-a90b-311bd2c0a447",
"note": "note",
"reviewList": [
    {
        "stageItemMember": "kol",
        "decisionTime": "15:15:15",
        "decisionDate": "11-12-2020"
    },
    {
        "stageItemMember": "qqqq",
        "decisionTime": "11",
        "decisionDate": "13-12-2020"
    },
    {
        "stageItemMember": "qqq7",
        "decisionTime": "18",
        "decisionDate": "14-12-2020"
    }
],
"NodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/990c4554-5499-44fe-9783-e3fbdb458d31",
"apps": "5"
```

}

Comment: @injecteer injecteer I changed the code in the question but still get the error

Comment: what does error say apart from 500?

Comment: @injecteer Internal Server Error only

Comment: I don't know if this will fix your problem, but I mocked up some working examples here - https://github.com/codetojoy/gists_groovy/tree/master/stack_overflow_65216335

Comment: @MichaelEaster thanks! but how can I add headers of authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with the code

```
def createUrl = new URL('http://logicased-mog.service.btlab.ru/alfresco/s')

def map = [:]
map["fromSoo"] = 'true'
map["attachments"] = attachments
map["signer"] = 'qqqe'
map["executor"] = 'qqqw'
map["isElectronicSign"] = 'true'
map["shortDescription"] = 'dskjh'
map["sheetsNumber"] = 3
map["note"] = 'dshsd'
map["reviewList"] = reviewList
map["NodeRef"] = ''
map["responseTo"] = 'workspace://SpacesStore/0fc89bec-7b62-4862-a90b-311bd2c0a447'
map["apps"] = 5
map["copies"] = 2

//create JSON
def jsonBody = new JsonBuilder(map).toString()

// build HTTP POST

def client = new RESTClient(createUrl)
client.auth.basic 'user1', 'user1' // auth
def resp = client.post(body : jsonBody, contentType: JSON)
return resp.data
```